# Dynamic Components in flex with validation

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5

How to Create Dynamic Flex Form Components with Validation??
is it Possible to Create Dynamic VO class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per creating a dynamic VO class, you can define a `dynamic class` in ActionScript in which properties may be added or removed.

```
public dynamic class EntityVO
{
    public function EntityVO()
    {
    }
}
```

Members may be added:

```
var entityVo:EntityVO = new EntityVO();    
entityVo.property1 = "New property";
```

Or removed:

```
delete entityVo.property1;
```